# Printing the result of a request to replicate a cUrl command

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm attempting to convert some curl commands that I can run successfully through my linux terminal. When running this command, I am VPN'd into a customers site. It is run on prem from a device on the LAN.

```
curl --anyauth "http://user:pass@192.168.1.1/vapix/call?format=simple&action=axcall:GetSIPConfiguration"
```

When inputting a valid user/pass and local address, I get the desired output through the terminal.

I ended up with the following:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://user:pass@192.168.1.1/vapix/call?format=simple&action=axcall:GetSIPConfiguration', verify=False))
```

This does not produce any errors, but how do I get the output to print properly (that's *if* it's working)?

Comment: What are you printing now?
Try printing response.txt. Also you might find more information in the requests library docs: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content

Answer (score 1):

You can do your request with:

```
import requests
import HTTPBasicAuth from requests.auth

url = 'http://192.168.1.1/vapix/call'
params = {'format': 'simple', 'action': 'axcall:GetSIPConfiguration'}
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'), params=params, verify=False)
```

And then print the status/error code of the response (and check if there were no error - for example check if the HTTP status code of the response is 2XX) with:

```
print(response.status_code)
```

You can also print the content of the response with:

```
print(response.text)
```

So all in all, you could for example print the content of the response only if it was successful (HTTP status code 200) with:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Well, that got me further than I was. Getting a 401 error in response.

Comment: You asked how to print the output. The authentification to your server is a different question plus it is specific to the credentials you provide.

Comment: I understand that, and it's much appreciated!

Comment: I know the credentials are good as I can use them when accessing the equipment, I'll have to take a look at how it's formatted.  When I use curl through my terminal it is formatted as //user:pass@192.168.x.x ,